# When trying to generate Java Tests in VS Code I get "Cannot find a valid classpath entry to generate tests."

Tags: java, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, junit

I try to use JUnit tests in a Java project in VS Code.

#### My setup

1) JDK 17

2) Via the **Extension Pack for Java** I have a its extensions installed including the following:

- Language Support for Java by Red Hat
- Debugger for Java
- Java Test Runner

3) I went to the **Testing** pane and downloaded (via the wizard) the testing JARs `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and `junit-4.13.2.jar` into the `lib` directory.

4) I made sure in **Classpath Configuration** the two JARs are listed under *Referenced Libraries*.

5) The project contains a main unqualified App.java with a main method and a qualified package like `org.mydomain.calculations`. **The method(s) which I want to test are in the qualified package!**

#### What I did then

In a class of the qualified package I right-click and choose from the context menu *Source Actions...*, then *Generate Tests...*. From the appearing project chooser I select the current project -- and then I get the error ballon "Cannot find a valid classpath entry to generate tests".

This confuses me, because I *did* add the JUnit JAR to the classpath.

*What else can I do to make generating tests in the qualified package work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install all extensions in the **[Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)** and use `Clean the java language server workspace` in the command palette to clean up the Java workspace.

[image]

**Follow the steps below to implement a minimal test example in vscode.**

1. Open the command palette(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and create a java project

   [image]
2. Add an **AppTest.java** file

   [image]
3. Select **Enable Java Tests** in the **Testing** panel

   [image]
4. select **JUit**

   [image]

It will automatically download third-party packages. The tests can then be run.

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. - But how can I make my real project using the testing framework? The real project is now not even anymore recognized as a Java project! (Probably because of the "Java: Clean Workspace" action...)

Comment: I have updated the question to explain that the problem might lie in the setup with a qualified package.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of your code, or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's a good idea to attach your folder structure if you can.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Today I'll put a reprex together.

Comment: I created a small example - and it just works (for the test generation). This means for me, that your answer is correct. :-)

Comment: For all people coming here later: The intermediate problems I had were related to the fact that I'm on Linux and I used symlinks in the path to the project folder. (See GitHub issue [JUnit tests not found on symlinked project folder](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/630)) As soon as I switched to the canonical path to open the folder in VS Code it all worked as expected.